# Is there a C/C++ Library to convert MathML <-> Infix?

Tags: c++, c, mathml

I'm looking for a C/C++ library that can convert MathML to infix and infix to MathML, eg given:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<math xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1998/Math/MathML">
  <apply>
    <times/>
    <cn type="integer"> 2 </cn>
    <ci> x </ci>
  </apply>
</math>
```

the library will convert the mathml to 2*x. Or given x+sin (t) I get the following mathml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<math xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1998/Math/MathML">
  <apply>
    <plus/>
    <ci> x </ci>
    <apply>
      <sin/>
      <ci> t </ci>
    </apply>
  </apply>
</math>
```

I know how to write such a library but would rather not reinvent the wheel if possible. Can't be in Java as I must be able to link the library to non-managed code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've never used it myself, but it looks as though libSBML might serve your purposes:

http://www.google.co.uk/search?q=libsbml+convert+mathml+infix

http://sbml.org/Software/libSBML/docs/cpp-api/libsbml-features.html

On this page:

http://sbml.org/Software/libSBML/docs/cpp-api/

It says:

"The libSBML formula parser has been carefully engineered so that transformations from MathML to infix string notation and back is possible with a minimum of disruption to the structure of the mathematical expression."

And has an example of what you're trying to do...

Comment: Its funny you should mention libSBML because that's what I am actually using at the moment. The only problem is that libSBML is 8.14 MB which is a bit much just for the functionality I am after. I've thought about trying to look at the code to take out the relevant sections but don't know how easy that would be. So I thought I'd ask first if there were any other solutions before I contemplate that route.

Comment: @rhody: D'oh! :) Sadly it's not something I've tried to do before, so I was just trying to dig something up for you - sorry I couldn't be more help.

Comment: I guess it just means there aren't many software libraries that do this. Would have thought it would have been more common. I appreciate the time you took to answer.